# get fatal error: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Sometimes we get error System.OutOfMemoryException . complete error is

> FATAL 2017-12-24 17:01:45,360 [39   ] Abp.AbpBootstrapper                      - System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
>      at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModule.FindDependedModuleTypes(Type moduleType) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModule.cs:line 108
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModule.AddModuleAndDependenciesRecursively(List`1 modules, Type module) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModule.cs:line 143
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModule.FindDependedModuleTypesRecursivelyIncludingGivenModule(Type moduleType) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModule.cs:line 124
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager.FindAllModuleTypes(List`1& plugInModuleTypes) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModuleManager.cs:line 86
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager.LoadAllModules() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModuleManager.cs:line 67
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager.Initialize(Type startupModule) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModuleManager.cs:line 40
>      at Abp.AbpBootstrapper.Initialize() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\AbpBootstrapper.cs:line 146
>   System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
>      at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModule.FindDependedModuleTypes(Type moduleType) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModule.cs:line 108
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModule.AddModuleAndDependenciesRecursively(List`1 modules, Type module) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModule.cs:line 143
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModule.FindDependedModuleTypesRecursivelyIncludingGivenModule(Type moduleType) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModule.cs:line 124
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager.FindAllModuleTypes(List`1& plugInModuleTypes) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModuleManager.cs:line 86
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager.LoadAllModules() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModuleManager.cs:line 67
>      at Abp.Modules.AbpModuleManager.Initialize(Type startupModule) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Modules\AbpModuleManager.cs:line 40
>      at Abp.AbpBootstrapper.Initialize() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\AbpBootstrapper.cs:line 146

we use ASPNetBoilerplate, AngularJs and entity framework

Comment: That doesn't look like the full stack trace. What did you do to get this error?

Comment: I took this error from logs.txt file after entire site stop work suddenly. Can this error related to backgroundJobs?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you've misconfigured ABP dependencies. **FindDependedModuleTypesRecursivelyIncludingGivenModule()** method recursively loads dependent modules and it might go into infinite loop. check all the  **[DependsOn(typeof(XXXX))]** attributes!

Comment: this fatal error raise rarely and we don't use  [DependsOn(typeof(XXXX))]  in project except those default usage in ASPNetBoilerplate template.

Comment: are you doing some heavy memory operations in module startups. that might be the case. all the module startups should be lite and fast loading.

Comment: We implement about 5 Background worker in webmodule's PostInitialize method . 4 of them have a light operation, but one of them have a injected appService with about 15 repository that

Comment: why did you implement background workers in web module. background jobs should run in a windows service. because the website can stop when it's idle.

Comment: BJobs implement in webModule and schedule with Quartz & crons. Other implementation is by windows service.

Comment: if you can reproduce the problem in a stable way, try removing background jobs one by one from module post initialize. this way you can see what's spoiling the fun.